# Notification not showing in notification tray even if permission is enabled

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am using Android 13 device for testing. Notification is receiving on version 11 and below but not on 12 and above. I have implemented notification permission also explored some stack answers but still did not find and solution. From firebase if i directly send test notification then it receives but it does not receiving from backend when some action is performed in app.

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for questions/issues regarding the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: You will probably need to add more details to your question. There isn't enough information in your question to even guess what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

In Android 12 and above, you also need to request the "group notification" permission.
here is an example how it can looks like:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
  if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.GROUP_NOTIFICATION)
      != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.GROUP_NOTIFICATION},
                      REQUEST_GROUP_NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION);
  }
}
```

And your have to add POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) {
   if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS},101);
       }
   else {
          createChannel();
        }
      }
```